# How to add 'Or' condition in assertion

Tags: jmeter

I want the request to pass  in both the cases if response contains "Completed" or "Progress, Will take time to process".

But if I include both this assertions in response assertion, it will take it as 'and'. It will pass only if both are satisfied.
Here any one of this is sufficient. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to go for an assertion which supports scripting, i.e. [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion)

1. Add Beanshell Assertion as a child of the request which returns either "Completed" or "Progress" messages
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   String response = new String(ResponseData);

   Failure = !(response.contains("Completed") || response.contains("Progress, Will take time to process"));
   ```

   Where:

   - `ResponseData` - byte array which holds parent sampler response
   - `Failure` - boolean which indicates whether parent sampler should be failed or not.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on how to use JMeter and Java API from Beanshell test elements and extend your JMeter tests with scripting.

Comment: Thank you sir. Its working fine with your logic. Your blog is also very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Jmeter 3.2](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) allow to check using Or condition

```
Response Assertion now allows to work on Request Header, provides a "OR" combination
```

[image]