# Response Assertion - JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want the request to pass in both the cases if response contains "status":0 or "status":"0".

But if I include both this assertions in response assertion, it will take it as 'and'. It will pass only if both are satisfied. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 'Or' condition in assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275886/how-to-add-or-condition-in-assertion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you use JMeter 3.2 (or later)

   [image: JMeter 3.2 Assertion]

   Reference: [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved)
2. If you use [previous JMeter versions](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) it still can be done but you will have to go for [regular expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

   [image]