# Scenario is passed even dynamic values present in response

Tags: jmeter

My script gets succesful(in VIew results tree all scenarios are in green color )eventhough dynamic values present in response in Jmeter , and if i check the application manually nothing is working,Could Please any one assist

Comment: Please add more details in the query.

Comment: I am trying to create a order id, and order id is creating when i run the script for first time but not the rest of times and script gets passed with 200 response code, could you please assist

Comment: So as @Dmitri suggested you can add a Response Assertion to check for the Text response should contain the orderID and Response Code should be 200 then only allow it to pass. More references on multiple condition with [Response Assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275886/how-to-add-or-condition-in-assertion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status codes below 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) as successful therefore JMeter will not automatically fail the HTTP Request sampler if response code is in the "successful" range.

If you want to add some extra checks for presence/absence of the specific content, request duration, etc. - add [JMeter Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps/) to your test, for instance [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) should be sufficient to cover the majority of use cases